# flutter how to add context to a custom class

Tags: flutter, localization

[image: context in a class flutter]

how can I get context for this class to utilize localization?
the error says to import dart.js but it dose not work

Comment: Hi I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try next. First, add constructor in your class to ask the property  BuildContext;

```
class MenuItems{

  BuildContext context;

  MenuItems({Key? key,required this.context});

    static Menultem home = MenuItem("${getLang(context,
    "Log out")}", Icons.home);
    static const notifications = MenuItem ('Notifications', Icons.notifications);
    static const history = MenuItem('History'
    , Icons.history_rounded);
    static const favorite = MenuItem ('Favorite', Icons.favorite)
```

Second,
In the place where you use your class put the context parameter.

```
MenuItems(context: context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `context` through constructor. But being static you can also create a method to initiate the context or convert home to a static method and pass context.

```dart
static MenuItem home({required BuildContext context})=> MenuItem(....)
```

Comment: can u refactor my code i could not get the idea.

Comment: try changing the `home` variable with answer snippet